# 'mysql' Command not Connecting as used from PATH but Works if Full Path is Used

Tags: mysql, django, xampp

Not sure how to fix this but here is the description. I can run the command to a Lampstack MySQL installation like this and it works:

```
/opt/lampstack/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

And my PATH variable has this path in it, but yet this command doesn't work:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Gives this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The command asks for password but then gives the error.

I should note as well that running phpMyAdmin works fine at `localhost:9090` with `root` and correct password.

Presumably, there are two MySQL installations getting confused, because I can run each command with `--version` and I get two distributions: 5.5.32 and 5.5.21.

This is a problem because I'm trying to use the Lampstack MySQL installation for a Django project. I have this configuration running on Windows but in an attempt to duplicate the environment on Ubuntu I've gotten a bit mixed up.

What is the best way to resolve this issue without removing the core MySQL on the Ubuntu system (and use the Lampstack one)?

**NOTE**

I discovered that the `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` doesn't actually exist and nor does the directory `/var/run/mysqld`. I'm not sure how to fix this so any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: The order of `$PATH` matters. It will use the first one it finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in which order in the `PATH` your `/opt/lampstack/mysql/bin/`. Is it before or after the native `mysql`binary? Run a

```
which mysql
```

to confirm. Make sure that `/opt/lampstack/mysql/bin/` appears BEFORE the other path.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you. I will accept the answer as soon as I can. In the meantime, I'm still getting connection errors through the server. What is the best way to flush this out so it uses the default binary in all places (still getting errors referring to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`)? The command `mysql -u root -p` is now working...

Comment: Depending on the case, I'd probably prepend the `PATH` in `/etc/profile.d/custom_mysql.sh` file, like put a line containing something like `export PATH=/opt/lampstack/mysql/bin/:$PATH` at the beginning of the file. Beware though that then the OS will probably default to using this new mysql aswell, which might break things, so I guess for you the best way is to have a check in there to, for example if there is a specific user only who should use this binary then add a check, or add the stanza to `~user/.bashrc` (or what ever shell that user is using)

Comment: What I ended up doing is actually reinstalled MySQL outside my Lampstack and then just dumped the db and created a new one. This way I co uld use the default socket without worrying about it...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to determine if something is accessible on your `$PATH` it's always best to use the command `type`.

```
$ type mysql
```

#### Example

```
$ type mysql
mysql is /usr/bin/mysql
```